# Beeline - Hive - how to remove additional (not needed) quotes?

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I am using Beeline to connect from one server to another and get data from Hive.

Command that I use is:

```
beeline --outputformat=tsv2 --silent  -e 'select * from t1 limit 3'
```

Output is:

```
a   "{""col1"": ""123"" } "
b   "{""col1"": ""234"" } "
c   "{""col1"": ""567"" } "
```

I need:

```
a   {"col1": "123" } 
b   {"col1": "234" } 
c   {"col1": "567" }
```

I tried with:

```
beeline --outputformat=tsv2 --silent  -e 'set system:disable.quiting.for.sv=false; select * from t1 limit 3'
```

but that gives NO output at all.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of col2 in the table

Comment: Data type is a String